# how to pass argument in php for executing shell command?

Tags: php, bash, shell

Here is the program listed below. I am trying to run the shell command from php so I have written the following code:

```
<?php    
$argument1 = $argv[1];    
$output = shell_exec('sudo whois ');    
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";    
?>
```

But every time I execute the command it get executed but doesn't display output. Only shows the option.

My command in shell is 
`php filename.php google.com`

Comment: `sudo`-ing commands from php, with no way of bashing in the password??

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using passed argument in your command. You need to use the argument in `whois` command:

```
<?php    
$argument1 = escapeshellarg($argv[1]);  
$output = shell_exec('whois '. $argument1);    
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";    
?>
```

PS: `whois` can tun without `sudo` also.

Comment: don't forget to shell-escape the input :-)

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for your help and what if i want to call these from web instead from command line...

Comment: Just replace above script with: `echo "<pre>" . shell_exec('whois '. $_GET['url']) . "</pre>";` and call your script as: `http://domain.com/shell.php?url=google.com`

Comment: Ya i just try to implement these i have two php page from one there is option for input the arguement and submit button then when i click submit button the output should redirect to the pop up php/html pages..i tried doing these please help me here

Comment: You need to make sure to use GET method in form action. Also create script as I commented above and access the direct URL as `http://domain.com/shell.php?url=google.com` once that is working then move on to your other script with submit button and form. If nothing works post your both PHP scripts in question so that I can debug it.